# Android Tab Layout tabs with round corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

This type of Question has already been asked before but not got any proper,working solution so I am again posting this question.Sorry for asking again and wasting your time.
Please give some working solution. Or let me know if I am doing anything wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Expected Tabs: [image: On select of Tab it should come like this]

But coming Like:

Coming Tabs
[image: Coming Tabs]

On page Load tabs are coming like "Expected Tabs" image but after selection coming like "Coming Tabs" image. 
**MainXML code:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_img_jpeg"
                android:minHeight="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/TRANSPARENT"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/blue" />
```

**@style/MyCustomTabLayout**

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
    </style>
```

**@drawable/tab_bg**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bgselected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bgnotselected" />
    </selector>
```

**@drawable/tab_bgselected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:bottom="0dp"  android:top="0dp"
          android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp">
            </corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Like that **@drawable/tab_bgnotselected**

And in code behind i have written:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                try {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    TabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                    TabCount = tabLayout.getTabCount();

                    try {
                        if (TabPosition == 0) {
                            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.policy_tab_blue);
                            drawable.setCornerRadii(new float[]{10,10,0,0,0,0,10,10}); // this will create the corner radious to left side

                        } else {
                            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.policy_tab_white);
                            drawable.setCornerRadii(new float[]{0,0,10,10,10,10,0,0}); // this will create the corner radious to right side

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("TabPosition:--->", TabPosition + "");
                    Log.i("TabCount:--->", TabCount + "");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use **MaterialCardView** with appropriate **cardCornerRadius** as a parent layout of `TabLayout` to achieve this one side rounded corner background. Then you can use **tabIndicatorColor** to colorize the tab selected layout. Hope this will help you. Thanks

*Code Snippet*:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    app:strokeColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"/>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

*Output*:
[image]

Comment: You also need `app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"` to make it works

Answer (score 10):

**If anyone looking for this type look(as shown in picture below) to tab layout**

[image: first tab selected]

[image: saved tab selected]

**In Xml TabLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/images_videos_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/tabview_bg"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
         />
```

**In Your Activity/Fragment**

> adding only customization code for brevity

```
val tabCount: Int = images_videos_tab_layout.tabCount

    for (i in 0 until tabCount) {
        val tabView: View = (images_videos_tab_layout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i)
        tabView.requestLayout()
        ViewCompat.setBackground(tabView,setImageButtonStateNew(requireContext()));
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(tabView, tabView.paddingStart, tabView.paddingTop, tabView.paddingEnd, tabView.paddingBottom);
    }

fun setImageButtonStateNew(mContext: Context): StateListDrawable {
    val states = StateListDrawable()
    states.addState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_normal_blue))
    states.addState(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_selected), ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_normal))

    return states
}
```

**In Drawable**

1.tab_bg_normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

2.tab_bg_normal_blue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/baseThemeColor" />
<corners android:radius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

3.tabview_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="25dp"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/baseThemeColor" android:width="1dp"/>
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 9):

**Result of below code:**

[image]

**Use 4 shapes (No need of selector) like:**

1. tab_left_select.xml

   ```
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item >
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
               <corners
                   android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                   android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp">
               </corners>
           </shape>
       </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
2. tab_left_unselect.xml

   - Same as above just change the color.
3. tab_right_select.xml

   - Same as above just change the radius direction to right.
4. tab_right_unselect.xml

   - Same as above just change the color and radius direction to right.

**In Your layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

**In your Activity/Fragment:**

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        setTabBG(R.drawable.tab_left_select,R.drawable.tab_right_unselect);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()==0) {
                    setTabBG(R.drawable.tab_left_select,R.drawable.tab_right_unselect);
                }
                else {
                    setTabBG(R.drawable.tab_left_unselect,R.drawable.tab_right_select);
                }
            }
            ....
        });

private void setTabBG(int tab1, int tab2){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            ViewGroup tabStrip = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            View tabView1 = tabStrip.getChildAt(0);
            View tabView2 = tabStrip.getChildAt(1);
            if (tabView1 != null) {
                int paddingStart = tabView1.getPaddingStart();
                int paddingTop = tabView1.getPaddingTop();
                int paddingEnd = tabView1.getPaddingEnd();
                int paddingBottom = tabView1.getPaddingBottom();
                ViewCompat.setBackground(tabView1, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(tabView1.getContext(), tab1));
                ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(tabView1, paddingStart, paddingTop, paddingEnd, paddingBottom);
            }

            if (tabView2 != null) {
                int paddingStart = tabView2.getPaddingStart();
                int paddingTop = tabView2.getPaddingTop();
                int paddingEnd = tabView2.getPaddingEnd();
                int paddingBottom = tabView2.getPaddingBottom();
                ViewCompat.setBackground(tabView2, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(tabView2.getContext(), tab2));
                ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(tabView2, paddingStart, paddingTop, paddingEnd, paddingBottom);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use **4 shapes:** 
  **1)** for left button not selected 
  **2)** for left button selected 
  **3)** for right button not selected 
  **4)** for right button selected

And then write selector to use for button background, see example for the left button (for the right just the similar):

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
  <gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#000"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:angle="-270"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#880f0f10"
        android:centerColor="#8858585a"
        android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>
   <corners
      android:topRightRadius="10dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
```

for more detail visit here. [Rounded corners for TABS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599755/rounded-corners-for-tabs-in-android)

Comment: after selecting 2nd tab its coming like "Coming Tabs" mentioned in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Form a previous answer here on StackOverflow for a creative developer that I didn't remember where it is, that can be done easily by having a card view as a parent view for the TabLayout

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.CustomTabText"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/green">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Today’s menu" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Full Menu" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reviews" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  for all corners

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient 
         android:startColor="#SomeGradientBeginColor"
         android:endColor="#SomeGradientEndColor" 
         android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners 
         android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

check how to use this in button or layout

http://www.techamongus.com/2017/02/android-layouts-with-round-corners.html

Answer (score 0):

With the Material-Design, we can make it simply by using **MaterialButtonToggleGroup** and adding MaterialButtons for the tabs.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/buttonGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:checkedButton="@+id/nearest">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/nearest"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Nearest" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/alphabetical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Alphabetical"/>

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

refer this link for more info - https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button-toggle-group/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my answer: (In my case, I JUST ADD Cardview above tabLayout and set radius corner).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlEmpty">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cvTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs_home"
            style="@style/customTabLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/tab_color"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customTabLayout" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerhome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cvTab" />
</RelativeLayout>
```