# how to make specific button side curved

Tags: android

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp" />
</shape>

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_list"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/width_100dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/my_background"/>
```

Tried the above code but it does not work for me. do i need to make a custom class extending button class.

[image: Should display like this]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9211208/2289835)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Easy!, Take CardView as root element. CardView rounds child elements edges according to itself.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ecb8ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Also if you need TabLayout. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35337754/6891563)

Comment: I think this is an overkill for just having rounded corners, it adds to hierarchy and comes with overdraw compared to using a shape.

Comment: @MelihAksoy Yes it adds hierarchy of views. But it does not have impact on performance. Did you worry ever about hundreds of items in List ever? It's just one. I tried to give a simple solution.

Comment: Appreciate the solution, added comment to help anyone looking for a more lightweight way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's a little tricky but it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="500dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="500dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```